# Nuxt 3: upload files to nuxt's server engine(nitro) using formdata and useFetch?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

So im writing an admin panel and need to send some image files and store them on backend

this is my example script in component using useFetch and formdata:

```
const {data,pending}=useFetch("/api/product",{
    method:"post",
    body:fd // Here i have my formdata containing files
})
```

server example (~/server/api/product.post.ts):

```
import {defineEventHandler,readBody} from "h3";

export default defineEventHandler(async(event) => {
  let body=await readBody(event); // I can get contents of my formdata here

  // Here i need to parse formdata and save it in server

  return {status:true, text:"saved successfully!"}
})
```

isn't there something like multer or anything to use it in nuxt's server engine (nitro)? and tell me if im doing something wrong

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solve it with the Busboy library.

first i create a file called useFiles.js with this content:

```
import Busboy from 'busboy'

const useFiles = async (event) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const { req } = event
    const files = []
    const fields = {}
    const busboy = Busboy({ headers: req.headers })
    busboy.on('file', (name, file, info) => {
      const { filename, encoding, mimeType } = info
      var chunks = []
      file.on('data', (chunk) => {
        chunks.push(chunk)
      })
      file.on('end', () => {
        files.push({
          fieldname: name,
          filename,
          encoding,
          mimetype: mimeType,
          buffer: Buffer.concat(chunks)
        })
      })
    })
    busboy.on('field', (name, value, info) => {
      fields[name] = value
    })
    busboy.on('finish', () => {
      resolve({ files, fields })
    })
    req.pipe(busboy)
  })
}

export default useFiles
```

and then implement it like this:

```
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  const { file, fields } = await useFiles(event) // file is a buffer


  return 'ready'
})
```

Comment: my solution only works for single file upload